# Create link for product image in Prestashop?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

What I'm trying to do is to get the category image to show instead of the product image. What I have done for the category product list which works is this.

This only works if you are looking at all the products in a category but not if you search for a product?

```
<a href="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="product_img_link" title="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
<img src="{$link->getCatImageLink($category->link_rewrite, $category->id_image, 'large_default')}" style="width:140px!important;" alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
</a>
```

I was wondering how do I get this to work all of the site? How do I make it pull the category images? Like it is above but for the whole site?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a multiple actions to create such an image, 
first of all you call for $category class in product page, so $category is not defined.

best solution is to create a assigment for $category in productController in override directory.

```
class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
                $category = new Category($this->product->id_category_default);
                $this->context->smarty->assign('category', $category);
    }
}
```

Comment: what page is this on and i appreciate it so much !

Comment: i added that but it still doesnt show the category image for the search ? did i do some thing qwrong ?

Comment: please reply i really need this

Comment: I really need this please you are the only one on 5 websites that has even tried to help me please !

Comment: do you clear prestashop class cashe? if not delete class_index.php in cashe folder.